# How to echo a jq JSON with double quotes escaped with backslash

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq, echo

I'm trying create a function that echoes the a JSON with escaped values with backslash like `"System.Title": "The \"title\" with double quotes"` property and when jq processes the echoed result returns a Parse error.

As you can see in the commented lines I've tried several ways to offset the effects of `echo` on backslash but I still cannot echo a parseable JSON.

Have someone successfully echoed a parseable JSON with escaped characters?

```
jsonWithEscapedCharacters='{
  "fields": {
    "System.AreaPath": "Here\\double-backslah",
    "System.IterationPath": "Ahother\\Double-backslash",
    "System.Title": "The \"title\" with double quotes"
  }
}'

getjsonWithEscapedCharacters() {
  # FAIL echo $jsonWithEscapedCharacters | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
  # FAIL echo "$jsonWithEscapedCharacters" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
  # FAIL echo -E "$jsonWithEscapedCharacters" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
  # FAIL echo "$jsonWithEscapedCharacters"
  # FAIL echo -e $jsonWithEscapedCharacters
  echo -e $jsonWithEscapedCharacters
}

echoedJson=$(getjsonWithEscapedCharacters)

titleFromJson=$(jq '.fields["System.Title"]' <<< $jsonWithEscapedCharacters)
title=$(jq '.fields["System.Title"]' <<< $echoedJson)

echo "expected $titleFromJson, actual: $title"
# jsonWithEscapedCharacters is parsed OK but echoedJson cannot be parsed due to jq Parse error
```

Comment: `jsonWithEscapedCharacters` already has appropriate escapes; adding more escapes *will* make it invalid JSON. Why are you trying to add more escapes? Also, you should (almost) always double-quote variable references, and avoid `echo` (and especially `echo -e`) for anything that includes escape characters, since they sometimes mangle them (use `printf `%s\n' "$variable"` instead).

Comment: Thx @GordonDavisson. I'm adding more escapes to counteract the effect of `echo` over the `jsonWithEscapedCharacters` variable inside `getjsonWithEscapedCharacters` function, but I can't find the way to make that function to return a JSON string parseable by jq

Comment: **Always** quote variables when expanding them. The same applies to command substitution

Comment: `echo -e` interprets escape sequences, turning `` \\ `` into `` \ ``. If you want to keep your escapes, then you must not interpret them. Why are you interpreting them? `echo` (without `-e`) leaves the backslashes intact.

Comment: Don't try to counteract the way `echo` mangles escapes; it's hopelessly inconsistent.C ontrary to @knittl's comment leaving `-e` off only helps with some versions in some modes, but not in others (see [this Unix&Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)). Just avoid the whole mess by not *ever* using `echo` with strings that might contain backslashes; use here-strings (`<<< "$var"`) or `printf` with an appropriate format string (`printf '%s\n' "$var"`), and remember to double-quote your variables, and you won't have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable content is already JSON-encoded. Just use quotes when using the variable:

```bash
jq . <<< "$jsonWithEscapedCharacters"
```

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "System.AreaPath": "Here\\double-backslah",
    "System.IterationPath": "Ahother\\Double-backslash",
    "System.Title": "The \"title\" with double quotes"
  }
}
```

Likewise, to retrieve some value (note the use of `-r` to strip the JSON encoding):

```bash
jq -r '.fields."System.Title"' <<< "$jsonWithEscapedCharacters"
```

```
The "title" with double quotes
```

Likewise with command substitution when storing that value:

```bash
title="$(jq -r '.fields."System.Title"' <<< "$jsonWithEscapedCharacters")"
echo "$title"
```

```
The "title" with double quotes
```